# Command Line findstr with a regular expression

Tags: regex, command-line, findstr

I need to search through all the files in a directory and sub directories to match any of the numbers in the reg exp.  Basically in our code we have blocks of code based on certain project numbers.  I need to find these blocks by project number.  This regular expression does what I need but I cannot get it to work at the command line

```
([^0-9]|^)(56|14|2)([^0-9]|$)
```

I tested this on https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html against this string "If session.projid = 56 and then again 14 or something else"

I am trying this at the command line

```
findstr /s /R /C:"([^0-9]|^)(56|14|2)([^0-9]|$)" *.*
```

But no results and I know there should be.  Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [these docs](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

> FINDSTR does not support alternation with the pipe character (|) multiple Regular Expressions can be separated with spaces, just the same as separating multiple words (assuming you have not specified a literal search with /C) but this might not be useful if the regex itself contains spaces.

In your case, you may use `\<` / `\>` word boundaries with each number and you may specify all your alternatives after a space:

```
findstr /s /r "\<56\> \<14\> \<2\>" *.*
```

Comment: Follow-up question, how do I fine only whole numbers in this expression?  Results of 14.29 are returning and so I only want the hole numbers.

Comment: @Dan I see, you may unroll the logic you used in your regex. `(^|[^0-9])` means match at the start or before a non-digit. So, you match `14` with `findstr /s /r "[^0-9]\<14\>[^0-9] ^14\>[^0-9] [^0-9]\<14$" *.*`. It will be a long expression for arbitrary amount of numbers, but this is just because findstr regex is not really a regular language engine :(.